# Want to commit some old code to git, that was saved in Visual SourceSafe, what files do I remove?

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have some old Visual Studio projects that were originally saved in a Visual SourceSafe (VSS) source control system - long since gone. Anyway, at this point all I have is the C# code and the files put there by Visual Studio, back in the day, when we used to use VSS. I used VSS for years, but only as an end user. How VSS actually stored files on the server, or how it coordinated this on client machines, such as mine, I don't know. I believe that files ending with extensions of .vssscc and maybe .scc are related to VSS. (This Visual Studio projects are old, so there's also files ending with .suo file extensions, but I suspect that has more to do with old versions of Visual Studio, rather than VSS.)

I'm hoping that someone here knows enough of VSS to verify that I'm correct about the files that Visual Studio would put on my machine for VSS. And are there any more files that Visual Studio would put onto a client's machine? Lastly can I just delete those .vssscc and .scc files from the project, before committing them to a git repo?

(I am not concerned about saving the history of these files - the latest version is fine with me.)

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/trevorr/vss2git)?

Comment: No, I haven't. I wasn't even aware of it, so thank you. However, in this case it won't work as the server for Visual SourceSafe is no longer in operation. The VSS database on that server, is done.

Comment: Saurabh, the link to vss2git answers my question. Thank you.